# DocuSign recipient sign date is not available via REST API while available via Connect XML event

Tags: docusignapi

When i check format of XML notification for Docusign Connect event - i observe `signed` field for recipient which contains date time of signment.
When i check REST API for envelope recipients i see that `signedDateTime` for recipient is `Reserved for DocuSign.`

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list

Why in one place it is available while in another - it is not?
Does REST API is something newer than XML event?
What is the most correct way to determine signment date for each recipient?

Answer (score 1):

making a call to get recipients using the DocuSign eSignature v2.1 API would include this data
See here
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Check the info for **dateSigned** inside the json